# AWS.Elastickbeanstalk Update 'No Environment found for EnvironmentName'

Tags: command-line-interface, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, aws-sdk, aws-cli

I am trying to update/upload my NodeJs application that is hosted on AWS Elastic Beanstalk.

I am using a command:

```
> aws elasticbeanstalk update-environment --application-name  my-app --environment-name  my-env --version-label ver1
```

And get en error:

> An error occurred (InvalidParameterValue) when calling the UpdateEnvironment operation: No Environment found for EnvironmentName = 'my-env'

However, i can see that **my-env** environment exists when I login to AWS console or run **eb list** from command line.

This is my config.yml file:

```
branch-defaults:
 master:
   environment: my-env
environment-defaults:
  my-env:
    branch: null
    repository: null
global:
  application_name: my-app
  default_ec2_keyname: null
  default_platform: arn:aws:elasticbeanstalk:us-east-1::platform/Docker running on
  64bit Amazon Linux/2.12.17
  default_region: us-east-1
  include_git_submodules: true
  instance_profile: null
  platform_name: null
  platform_version: null
  profile: eb-cli
  sc: git
  workspace_type: Application
```

Any guidance is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I can see that the elastic beanstalk environment is configured to deploy to the `us-east-1` region.Your eb-cli must be using some other region.

I would try doing `eb list --region us-east-1` to confirm my theory.

Comment: sorry I got it wrong, I thought you don't see the environment when you do `eb list`